# Combining 2 Observables so that one emits the next value only when the second emits

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, reactive

I have an Observable **Obs1** which has been created with the method `from` starting from an Array of objects.

Let's assume the Array has 10 objects, this means that **Obs1** emits 10 times and then terminates.

For each of the objects emitted by **Obs1** I want to execute a function which returns an Observable. The Observables returned by the function are therefore of the same number as the elements of the Array, let's call them **Obs2-1** **Obs2-2** ... **Obs2-10**. Such Observables emit just 1 value and then complete.

I would like to link somehow **Obs1** to series of Observables **Obs2-1** ... **Obs2-10** so that **Obs1** emits its *(n+1)-th value* when **Obs2-*n*** emits.

A real example can make this thing more clear. Let's assume I have an array of strings. Each string is the name of a file. I have a function `r-w-files(files: Array<string>)` which reads each file in the list and writes it in another directory.

I want to execute this read write logic for a big number of files and therefore, to avoid having too many files open at the same time, I want to divide the big initial list in smaller chunks and then SEQUENTIALLY process them with the function `r-w-files(files: Array<string>)`.

What I am imagining is to have a certain form of buffer of chunks which

- emits the first chunk and passes it to `r-w-files(files:
  Array<string>)`
- it then waits until the Observable returned by
  `r-w-files(files: Array<string>)` completes
- once it completes it    passes the second chunk to `r-w-files(files:
  Array<string>)`
- and so on

Is there any way to implement such logic with Observable operators?

Comment: Have you seen [zip operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) ?

Comment: thanks for the answer - unfortunately my original question was not really clear and did not explain the full problem I am facing - I have edited the question with more details (the zip operator would have worked with my original question but not my real problem, thanks anyways)

Comment: Don't you just need [`bufferCount`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/bufferCount.ts)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch Observables sequentially, you can use **concatMap**:

```
Rx.Observable.from(['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3'])
  .concatMap(value => createNewObservable(value))
  .subscribe()
```

**concatMap** waits until the previously created Observable completes before switching to the next one.

Comment: thanks for the answer - unfortunately my original question was not really clear and did not explain the full problem I am facing - I have edited the question with more details (the zip operator would have worked with my original question but not my real problem, thanks anyways)